# Get the last inserted id from table in hibernate from MySql database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an entity named Item in which i have declared a property

@Column(name="ITEM_CODE", unique = true, length=30)
private String itemCode

while inserting a new item in the corresponding table i am trying to generate a unique code by prefixing it PRO- and then concatenating a random number generated by using Random class.
I am also trying to get the last item id inserted in the database and add 1 with the id and then add it to the product code as suffix.
My code to fulfill my purpose is

public String generateItemCode() {

```
String query = "SELECT max(i.id) FROM ITEM i";
List list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).list();
int nextInsertId = ((Integer) list.get(0)).intValue() + 1;
Random random = new Random();
int number = random.nextInt(9999 - 1 + 1) + 1;
return "" + number+nextInsertId;
```

}

I have also tried by using this line of code in the method body.

```
int maxId= (Integer)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select max(id) from items").uniqueResult();
```

the above code is not working.
How can i get the last inserted id. Is there any simpler way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you using Hibernate's ID generators?

Answer (score -1):

It appears your issue may likely be because of your query syntax mimicing that of native SQL when in reality you aren't asking Hibernate to execute a native query but instead a HQL/JPQL query.

If we assume your entity is named `Item` with an identifier property named `id`, you would use:

```
SELECT max(i.id) FROM Item i
```

You'll notice I use the property name `id` and the entity name `Item` (case is important here).

To put the pieces together, the following should work:

```
// be sure to check for null lastId in case you have no items.
final String sql = "SELECT max( i.id ) FROM Item i";
Integer lastId = (Integer) session.createQuery( sql ).uniqueResult();
```

Comment: This is a very bad practice. If another sql session comes in inserts into the table, then this can change your output. I worked at a place that did this and then spent nearly a year fixing code similar to what is mentioned in this answer. Use some form of a last_insert_id that is specific to the sql dialect.